# How to set a line style as default for multiple plots in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to create plot using gnuplot. The line width should be 3 in all plots. If I do it for one plot only this is done by:

```
set style line 1 linewidth 3
```

Is there any way how to do it globally as default?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can specify

```
set terminal <terminal> linewidth 3
```

This will change the default linewidth for all lines in the plot, including the plot borders.

If that's not what you want, you can specify all the lines in a loop (gnuplot 4.6+), where `n` is the number of lines you are plotting:

```
do for [i=1:n] {
    set style line i linewidth 3
}
```

Comment: You can do the same thing with gnuplot 4.4 `set for [i=1:n] style line i linewidth 3`

Comment: Also not that there is `set termoption lw 3` to set the linewidth to 3 for the current terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There are also other "line styles" that are set for all lines at once without index, e.g., for `linespoints`:

```
set style data linespoints
plot '-', '-'
    1, 1
    2, 2
    3, 3
    e
    1, 1
    2, 4
    3, 9
    e
```

Have a look at the "Style" section of the TOC of the manual http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf for other things that can be set by default.