# How to change dot size in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How to change point size and shape and color in gnuplot.

```
plot "./points.dat" using 1:2 title with dots
```

I am using above command to plot graph ,but it shows very small size points.

I tried to use command

```
set pointsize 20
```

but still point size is same.

Answer (score 82):

Use the `pointtype` and [`pointsize`](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/pointsize.html) options, e.g.

```
plot "./points.dat" using 1:2 pt 7 ps 10
```

where `pt 7` gives you a filled circle and `ps 10` is the size.

See: [Plotting data](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-data/).

Comment: Is there a simple way to specify pointsize in pixels?  If the answer is complicated, just say no and I'll make a separate question.

Comment: @JaredBeck sorry, I don't have a quick answer. You probably stand a better chance with a new questions.

Comment: Can we change the default point size for all plots without having to specify it for each one individually?

Comment: @Tarek - see [this answer to: How to set a line style as default for multiple plots in Gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14924457/2043505).

Comment: It seems that `ps` has no effect when the point type is a character like `"X"`. For example both  `pt "X" ps 10` and `pt "X" ps 100` plot the same point size.

Answer (score 10):

The [pointsize command](http://www.gnuplotting.org/manpage-gnuplot-4-6/#Q1-1-562) scales the size of points, but does not affect the size of dots.

In other words, `plot ... with points ps 2` will generate points of twice the normal size, but for `plot ... with dots ps 2` the "`ps 2`" part is ignored.

You could use circular points (`pt 7`), which look just like dots.

Answer (score 0):

plot "./points.dat" using 1:2 title with dt 2 lw 4