# Is it possible to change point size in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How can I change the dot size in gnuplot. All of my searches show that I can use

```
plot .... with points <point_type> <point_size>
```

For example, `with points 1 10` works fine. However there is no such option for `with dots` and it says it is not allowed here. Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change point size in gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697283/how-to-change-point-size-in-gnuplot)

Comment: It seems that `ps` has no effect when the point type is a character like `"X"`. For example both  `pt "X" ps 10` and `pt "X" ps 100` plot the same point size.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why do you want to change your dot size, when you can chose filled circles as symbols?
Try this command:

```
plot ... with points pointtype 7 pointsize 5
```

Here

- `pointtype` (or `pt`) allows you to select different symbols (Each terminal has a default set of line and point types, which can be seen by using the command `test`, e.g. pngcairo: `pt 5` would be a filled square)
- `pointsize` (or `ps`) allows you to control the size, as you had mentioned before.

I think the difference between a `dot` and a `point` is, that `dot` will always be a pixel-dot. If you are looking for more flexibility, `points` will allow that.

Comment: broken link on the complete list

Comment: @GrayCygnus thanks. I have removed the link and provided different information on how to determine available point types