# Drawing a 3D helix and spheres in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm trying to produce an object (at least the helix and points) very similar to this one:

[image]

The formula for drawing a helix is this:

[image]

Now suppose I take a = 1 and R = 1.

I tried using gnuplot like this:

```
splot [t=-20:20] cos(t), sin(t), t
```

That's good start, I'd need to find the right a and R settings or change the axis displayed.

[image]

How do I add little spheres on given coordinates to the same plot? Say:

```
(0,1,1) -> size 0.2
(1,1,2) -> size 0.1
```

Comment: Just a remark: If your primary aim is "drawing" and not "plotting", you might want to have a look at LaTex and its PGF/tikz engine. (see some [mathematical examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/mathematical-engine/)).  
With tikz you can produce some high-quality illustrations such as the one you included in your post

Comment: True, as I understand it, you can also use gnuplot in latex.

Comment: That's right! You can use gnuplot directly from latex (package gnuplottex). But gnuplot is primarily made for plotting data. If you want draw something, tikz is sometimes a better choice. Don't get me wrong! gnuplot is my favorite plotting tool. All I want to say is that depending what your goal is, there are different tools...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a combination of the linked sites, you can overlay [individual symbols](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-single-points/) onto your plot, draw [arrows for the lines and place labels](http://www.gnuplotting.org/understand-parametric-plotting/).

1. For the symbols, predefine line styles, by using e.g.

   ```
   set style line 1 lc rgb 'blue' pt 7
   ```

   to give you a blue circle. [Different symbol sizes can be set with the `ps` command.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16697571/2043505)
2. With the call to `splot`, you can tell gnuplot to use the standard input (`'-'`). This has to be repeated for each symbol:

   ```
   '-' w p ls 1
   ```

   will give you a single point with the symbol defined by `ls 1`. Use different `ls` definitions for different symbols.
3. after the  `splot` command, you need to define the coordinates for each of the symbols, followed by `e` to end the input.
   In this example, we have two points, one at `1. 0. 0.` and one at `-1. 0. 9.42`
4. Use `set arrow` and `set label` to have a connecting line and label.

You can combine all that into the a script:

```
set parametric
unset key

set style line 1 lc rgb 'blue' pt 7
set style line 2 lc rgb 'red' pt 7
set style line 3 lc rgb 'green' pt 7 

splot [t=0:3*pi] cos(t),sin(t),t, '-' w p ls 1,  '-' w p ls 2
1. 0. 0.
e
-1. 0. 9.42
e

p1 = 3.*pi
set arrow from 1,0,0 to -1,0,p1 nohead ls 3 
set label 'A' at -1.1,-0.1,9.52
```

This example will result in:

[image: example]

Comment: Excellent answer! One small remark. How would I make one of the dots larger in size?

Comment: Check out [my answer to this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16697571/2043505)