# Plot point size not changing

Tags: gnuplot

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697283/how-to-change-dot-size-in-gnuplot) the `ps` setting can be used to change the point size of a plot:

```
plot "./points.dat" using 1:2 pt 7 ps 10     # small point size
plot "./points.dat" using 1:2 pt 7 ps 100    # large point size
```

However `ps` seems to be ignored when using a character point type:

```
plot "./points.dat" using 1:2 pt "X" ps 10     # small point size
plot "./points.dat" using 1:2 pt "X" ps 100    # small point size
```

How to change the point size for character point types like `"X"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
plot '+' u 1:1 w p pt "X" font ",10"
plot '+' u 1:1 w p pt "X" font ",100"
```